# Dart Observable Change Handler

Tags: dart, observer-pattern

I'm looking for a way to use a handler function to respond to changes to an observable collection in Dart. I want to pipe my change directly to a function.

```
List things = toObservable([]);
//...
things.onChange.listen((e) => onThingsChanged(e) ); //blows up
//...
function onThingsChanged(e){
   //...
}
```

There obviously isn't such thing as `onChange`, so what am I looking for here? All the examples I find are just watching the changes with a `<template>` tag in the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good (official) article about [Observables and Data Binding with Web UI](http://www.dartlang.org/web-ui/observables/). I think it is still under construction and thus there are no links on the dartlang.org website yet.

The part that answers your question is: [Expression Observers](http://www.dartlang.org/web-ui/observables/#expression-observers)

You can do something like this:

```dart
List things = toObservable([]);

observe(() => things, onThingsChanged);

onThingsChanged(ChangeNotification e) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't work out of WebUI context. E.g. if you want to do it inside library code as general observable list, handlers are not triggered - the changes are queued, but they are not delivered. Explicit call to `deliverChangesSync();` is required.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I missed that part when I read that doc. I don't really get why the first argument has to be ()=>things instead of just things. Can you explain?

Comment: `observe` takes a function which returns an `Observable` instance. There is also `observeChanges` which takes just an observable so you can call `observeChanges(things, onThingsChanged)`

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic, why didn't you post that as an answer? It works. I got the observe function to work too, but the second argument has to be modified: observe(() => things, (e) => onThingsChanged(e));

observeChanges seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 2):

Few additions to Marco's answer which might not be obvious.

Besides `observe` which takes an expression, you can also use `observeChanges` which takes an instance of `Observable`, so you can write `observeChanges(things, (c) => ...)`.

More important is the fact that if you use `ObservableList` outside of Web UI context (e.g. in a standalone script), the changes will not be triggered immediately. Instead, changes are queued and you need to call `deliverChangesSync` to trigger the notifications. The listener will then get notified with list of changes.